# Norm of identity operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $1<p,q<\infty$, so I need to find a norm of identity operator $J: l^n_p \to l^n_q$

When $p\le q$, it's quite easy for me to understand that $||J||=1$ (beacuse in this case $||x||_q \le ||x||_p$, so $\frac{||x||_q}{||x||_p} \le 1$ and it's easy to find vector on which  $\frac{||x||_q}{||x||_p} = 1$ )

But when $p > q$, things get trickier. So I have a hypotesis that the answer in this case is $\frac{n^{1/q}}{n^{1/p}}$ and I had some approach to prove it but I couldn't finish it

Comment: What is your definition of the identity operator?

Comment: $J(x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1,...x_n)$

Comment: Hölder's inequality gives that the norm is at most $\frac{n^{1/q}}{n^{1/p}}$ and this is achieved for $x = (1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific, cause I tried to use Hölder's inequality so many times and I got so many inequalities but didn't get what I needed?

Comment: All right I got it

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^q \leqslant \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1^{p/(p-q)}\right)^{(p-q)/p}\cdot \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^p\right)^{q/p}$, what gives us $\frac{||x||_q}{||x||_p} \le \frac{n^{1/q}}{n^{1/p}}$